# format to 3 decimal places all decimal number in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

```
index,Adj Close,Close,High,Low,Open,SMA_100,SMA_20,SMA_5,SMA_50,Volume,code,date_of_trade
0,2.8999999999999999,2.8999999999999999,2.9700000000000002,2.8300000000000001,2.9300000000000002,3.8003000000000009,3.2214999999999998,3.1319999999999992,3.0767999999999969,631100,1PG,2016-02-05 00:00:00
```

The above is my file. What I want to do is limit all decimal number to 3 decimal places( like 2.333) and write to another file . I am using python to read file. Is there anyway of doing it at file level rather at each column level? If it need to be done at column level what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))    # write header

    for cols in csv_input:
        for i in xrange(1, 10):
            cols[i] = '{:.3f}'.format(float(cols[i]))
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

This would give you an output file as follows:

```
index,Adj Close,Close,High,Low,Open,SMA_100,SMA_20,SMA_5,SMA_50,Volume,code,date_of_trade
0,2.900,2.900,2.970,2.830,2.930,3.800,3.221,3.132,3.077,631100,1PG,2016-02-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want correct rounding, you will have to read each column and convert it to an integer. If you keep it as a string, best you can do is truncating the number to 3 digits after the decimal point.

In order to round, you should use the `round` primitive (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round)).

If truncating is enough, you will still have to read the file line by line and write the output to a new one, but you could use a regex. In essence, what you'll want to do is :

```
import re

for line in file:
    newline = re.sub(r"(\d\.\d{3})(\d*)", r"\1", line)
    print(newline, file=newfile)
```

The first solution will give this :

```
index,Adj Close,Close,High,Low,Open,SMA_100,SMA_20,SMA_5,SMA_50,Volume,code,date_of_trade
 0,2.9,2.9,2.97,2.83,2.93,3.8,3.221,3.132,3.0768,631100,1PG,2016-02-05 00:00:00
```

And the second one this :

```
index,Adj, Close,Close,High,Low,Open,SMA_100,SMA_20,SMA_5,SMA_50,Volume,code,date_of_trade
0,2.899,2.899,2.970,2.830,2.930,3.800,3.221,3.131,3.076,631100,1PG,2016-02-05 00:00:00
```

Comment: can you please explain 2 line about reg expression

Comment: Yes sure.
```re.sub``` allows me to replace stuff. The first argument will be the matched expression, the second one the replacement. ```\d``` matches a digit.  The parenthesis are used to build groups, that can later be referenced. First, we match {digit}{decimal point}{3digits}, that is done using ```\d\.\d{3}```. This is our first group. Then we match the remaining digits, using ```\d*```. This is our second group. Our replacement expression will be {first group}, so just ```\1```.