# Truncate numbers to 3 decimal places in CSV file while ignoring strings

Tags: python, csv, decimal

So I have a CSV file with a whole mess of numbers and words and I need to truncate the numbers to three decimal places, but everything I've tried so far doesn't work because of the strings: I get an error message saying 
'could not convert strings to floats'.

I used the code suggested here: [format to 3 decimal places all decimal number in csv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266955/format-to-3-decimal-places-all-decimal-number-in-csv-file-python/35267338#35267338)

and got that error.

The code looks something like (assume all indents are correct):

```
with open('metaanalysis_data.csv', 'rb') as f_input, 
open('metaanalysis_datas.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, quotechar="'")
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for cols in csv_input:
        for i in cols:
            for i in xrange(1, 10):
            #if i != str:
                cols[i] = '{:.3f}'.format(float(cols[i]))
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

I tried adding:

```
if i is float:
```

before 'for i in xrange(1, 10)' and I tried the same thing after and it cleared up my error message but resulted in a file that hadn't been modified at all.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You can use `if not isinstance(cols[i], str):` but I suggest you read up on indexing and datatypes, because your syntax is off (you've got bigger problems). You're using `i` twice in your loop and even if that was correct, it doesn't make sense to test the `type` of `i`, because that's just your index variable. Also you're reading and writing to the same file, which is definitely bad. Lastly, we can't just "_assume all indents are correct._"

Comment: adding the line you suggested did not result in an error message, but it also did not result in my decimals being rounded or truncated. Also, if you look more carefully at the code, you will see I am reading and writing to two different files. I said that about the indents because I do not know how to copy and paste with the indents intact and I wanted to make it clear that indents were not the problem.

Comment: You're right- by the time I noticed that the filenames were different, it was too late to edit my post. However, indentation is critical to python- you can manually add them to your post using spaces. Can you provide a small sample input and the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using pandas in Python, you should be able to get this done like this:

```
# load pandas package
import pandas as pd

# read in initial file
dataset = pd.read_csv('metaanalysis_data.csv')

# create function that tries to round input to three decimal places,
# returns input if failure occurs (e.g. if not a float)
def try_cutoff(x):

    try:
        return round(float(x), 3)
    except Exception:
        return x

# loop over each column and apply try_cutoff to each element in each column
for field in dataset.columns:


    dataset[field] = dataset[field].map(try_cutoff)

# write new dataset result to CSV file
dataset.to_csv("some_new_file.csv", index = False)
```

So, effectively, this creates a function, try_cutoff, that will attempt to round an element to three decimal places.  If it hits a string, then it'll just return that string.  Then, you run this over each column in your data frame, and write the new data frame out to a file.

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you; this worked perfectly. Do I have to close the files after, or does that happen automatically?

Comment: The connection will close automatically when you run the "dataset.to_csv" line, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I like this answer because it maintains the `float` datatype for the values. Using `'{:.3f}'.format()` converts the numbers to strings, and consequently, they will be written to the file with quotes around the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that only some of the values in the CSV are float, but for the rest the conversion will fail. You can try:

```
with open('metaanalysis_data.csv', 'rb') as f_input, 
open('metaanalysis_datas.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, quotechar="'")
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for row in csv_input:
        for i, elem in enumerate(row):
            try:
                row[i] = '{:.3f}'.format(float(elem))
            except ValueError: pass
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

That way, when the conversion fails it will raise a `ValueError` exception and the element `row[i]` will remain what it was.

Comment: @pault Whops, thanks, you're right, I copypasted the original snippet without much reading and changed only the relevant part (interestingly, the code did about the same anyway, only repeating things more...). I fixed it and improved a bit.

Comment: So I tried this, but it only resulted in the final row of data being written and can't figure out why that would happen. I tried just using 'try' in the original code, but it did like you said and ended up repeating things.

Comment: @birdoptera Only the last row was written because the indentation is incorrect (ironic considering our exchange on your original question). The last line should be indented so that the output is written _inside_ the `for` loop. Indentation is important in python!